# Printing more than one graph at a time

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am quite new to python so please bear with me.

My code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/aaronhuang/Desktop/ffp/exfileCLEAN2.csv", skiprows=[1])
magnitudes = df['Magnitude '].values
times = df['Time '].values
zscores = np.abs(stats.zscore(magnitudes, ddof=1))
outlier_indicies = np.argwhere(zscores > 3).flatten()
numbers = print(times[outlier_indicies])



window = 2
num = 1
x = times[outlier_indicies[num]- 
window:outlier_indicies[num]+window+1]
y = magnitudes[outlier_indicies[num]- 
window:outlier_indicies[num]+window+1]


plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('Time (units)')
plt.ylabel('Magnitude (units)')
plt.show()
fig = plt.figure()
```

What prints is:

```
/Users/aaronhuang/.conda/envs/EXTTEst/bin/python 
 "/Users/aaronhuang/PycharmProjects/EXTTEst/Code sandbox.py"
[2455338.895 2455350.644 2455391.557 2455404.776 2455413.734 2455451.661
 2455473.49  2455477.521 2455507.505 2455702.662 2455734.597 2455765.765
 2455776.575 2455826.593 2455842.512 2455866.508 2455996.796 2456017.767
 2456047.694 2456058.732 2456062.722 2456071.924 2456082.802 2456116.494
 2456116.535 2456116.576 2456116.624 2456116.673 2456116.714 2456116.799
 2456123.527 2456164.507 2456166.634 2456391.703 2456455.535 2456455.6
 2456501.763 2456511.616 2456519.731 2456525.49  2456547.588 2456570.526
 2456595.515 2456776.661 2456853.543 2456920.511 2456953.496 2457234.643
 2457250.68  2457252.672 2457278.526 2457451.89  2457485.722 2457497.93
 2457500.674 2457566.874 2457567.877 2457644.495 2457661.553 2457675.513]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aaronhuang/PycharmProjects/EXTTEst/Code sandbox.py", line 15, in <module>
    xdata = times[outlier_indicies[numbers] - window:outlier_indicies[numbers] + window + 1]
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Process finished with exit code 1
```

A snippet of Data frame is:

```
           Time   Magnitude   Magnitude error 
0     2455260.853      19.472             0.150
1     2455260.900      19.445             0.126
2     2455261.792      19.484             0.168
3     2455262.830      19.157             0.261
4     2455264.814      19.376             0.150
...           ...         ...               ...
6096  2457686.478      19.063             0.176
6097  2457689.480      19.178             0.128
6098  2457690.475      19.386             0.171
6099  2457690.480      19.092             0.112
6100  2457691.476      19.191             0.122
```

I am trying to take each number separately printed above, search for it in the data frame, and graph the number and 10 plots on either side.

My final result should print around 60 separate graphs at once

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is a link to the data set, available for download.

[1]https://spaces.hightail.com/space/BZuCAsY4nO

Comment: 60 separate graphs? Do you mean multiple lines overlayed onto the same axis? You'll need to loop through 60 times and call `ax.plot` on each one.

Comment: I was thinking of 60 separate graphs, not on the same axis. Or is there a way to one pop up after closing the other. @MateenUlhaq

Comment: You could display them in a large tiled grid of 60 separate axes within the same figure. But if you really want 60 separate figures, you can just plot a single line, display, then create a new plot and display that, ...

Comment: How would you code this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to draw multiple graphs is to use `plt.subplots()`. It's easy. The data is created appropriately.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
times = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', freq='1d', periods=6000)
mag = np.random.randint(0,20, (6000,))
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':times, 'Magnitude':mag})

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axes = plt.subplots(6, 10, figsize=(30,30))

for i in range(6):
    for j in range(10):
        x = df.iloc[j*10:(j+1)*10,:]
        axes[i][j].plot(x['Time'], x['Magnitude'])
        axes[i][j].set_xticklabels(x['Time'].dt.date, rotation=45)
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**
I ran the above code using the published data. The graph has been successfully displayed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, when I print the code above, it only prints out one singular graph and many empty graphs. Would you be able to help me fix this? Thanks,  @r-beginners

Comment: Currently it saves as a PNG

Comment: I received your comment and actually saved it in PNG format to check it out. It was as the image in the answer. Is it a problem with the environment? My environment is 'matplotlib 3.2.2' and 'python 3.6.6'

Comment: Ok i got the graph working, I needed to add plt.show to the bottom. Can you help me change this part of the code



`window = 2
num = 1
x = times[outlier_indicies[num]-window:outlier_indicies[num]+window+1]
y = magnitudes[outlier_indicies[num]-window:outlier_indicies[num]+window+1]


plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('Time (units)')
plt.ylabel('Magnitude (units)')
plt.show()
fig = plt.figure()`

to show all the graphs at once?

Comment: Currently it only prints one at a time, chosen by num

Comment: What is the purpose of the code presented? We can't do anything about it because we don't have the data here.

Comment: I would be happy to share the data if that's alright with you?

Comment: Go ahead and add to the question.

Comment: The data is a long csv file, how should I put it into the question?

Comment: Some data that can be released, or if you can't release it, then I think it's just the number of sample data that you can put in the question.

Comment: I have uploaded the data set onto a website. Thank you for helping me

Comment: It did not result in an error. What is the issue? I recommend that this be a new question, as it's impossible to exchange new requirements in the comments feature . Numerous other respondents are available. That's a shortcut to solving your problem.

Comment: I am trying to integrate plt.subplots into my code so it printed more than one graph at once, so it looked like yours did in the first image. I have put up another question requesting help if you would be happy continuing to help me there.